# Is there a faster way to compare if Number is in range?

Tags: java, android, primitive

I'm using code bellow to check if numbers in array is in range:

```
private static final int page_red = 130;
private static final int page_green = 140;
private static final int page_blue = 135;

private boolean isPageColor(double[] color) {
    return color[0] >= page_red - 25 && color[0] <= page_red + 25
                && color[1] >= page_green - 25 && color[1] <= page_green + 25
                && color[2] >= page_blue - 25 && color[2] <= page_blue + 25;
}
```

---

Is there a faster way(**more performance**) to do this?

---

Looking at your advices (especially @VikrantKashyap and @TDG) I made edit:

```
    private static final int delta = 25;

    private static final int page_red_min = page_red - delta;
    private static final int page_green_min = page_green - delta;
    private static final int page_blue_min = page_blue - delta;

    private static final int page_red_max = page_red + delta;
    private static final int page_green_max = page_green + delta;
    private static final int page_blue_max = page_blue + delta;

    private boolean isPageColor(double[] color) {
        return color[0] >= page_red_min && color[0] <= page_red_max
                && color[1] >= page_green_min && color[1] <= page_green_max
                && color[2] >= page_blue_min && color[2] <= page_blue_max;
    }
```

---

I think it's a little bit faster now (because of less +- operations).

Comment: if your `int` values are fixed Constant then why are you not using value instead Of  `page_red - 25` or .... @VladimirKulyk

Comment: @VikrantKashyap nice point. It's just an example. Question is still opened (what is the fastest way to do this)

Comment: You can use apache common validator as an alternate, [`isInRange()`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/DoubleValidator.html#isInRange(double,%20double,%20double)) like `isInRange(color[0],page_red,page_blue)`.

Answer (score 1):

Change the value of the constants to the **minimal** value:
`private static final int page_red = 105;`

and check the following -

```
color[0] >= page_red && color[0] <= page_red + 50
```

It saves you one substraction per color, and upto 3 per call.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Math

```
private boolean isPageColor(double[] color) {
    return Math.max(page_red - 25,color[0]) == Math.min(color[0], page_red - 25);

}
```

Comment: `Math` class will take more time than a `native` Operator like `==` , `<=` or `>=` . Isn't So ??

Comment: This comparison is always false unless the value is exactly page_red - 25. You may want to replace the minus with a plus in the second term.

Comment: @VikrantKashyap That is also what I was wondering. I thought about creating the variables at the begining and that would be more efficient if absolutely all conditions were tested all the time which is not the case. I am begining to think that maybe the actual implementation in the question is the highest performant one.

Answer (score 0):

Here I've changed my previous answer a bit.

Purely based on **performance** I would say that what might improve it, is just if you pull some variables out before starting the comparison and actally using them in your method. You may not have a reason to create the array in the first place. If you don't need this array at all and you are only using it to make it easy to pass parameters then you should consider actually passing each of the color:

```
private boolean isPageColor(double color0, double color1, double color2) {
    return color0 >= page_red - 25 && color0 <= page_red + 25
                && color1 >= page_green - 25 && color1 <= page_green + 25
                && color2 >= page_blue - 25 && color2 <= page_blue + 25;
}
```

This way you avoid re-accessing the array which will save you not really a lot but you will get definitelly get you some more extra microseconds.

So basically I'm making use of the && operator short-circuit property and the fact that I don't need to create the three variables in the begining of the method which would actually lower performance because not all conditions need to be tested. They are 6 and it only takes one for the whole thing to fail.

Comment: If the first comprasion fails, there's no need to access the other two variables.

Comment: @JoaoEsperancinha i'm using OpenCV, and take pixel color as `double[]` (red, green, blue, alpha), so input parameter should be `double[]`.

Comment: @TDG Thanks for the input. I've made a few changes. The array for me isn't such a great idea to pass and if it's creation is not needed then we can have the performance improvement I was looking for.

Comment: @VladimirKulyk Then I would say that it looks like you've reached the highest possible performant solution. It doesn't look like very elegant code, but in your case, it's actually more efficient because it is avoiding a lot of unecessary calculations. The use of Math will only make your code look nicer but will damage performance.